# Display all lead record along with Notes in vf page without apex

Tags: visualforce

I want to display all notes with a lead record like

```
| Lead| Notes| 
|:---- |:------:| 
| john|  call to customer   | 
| john|  update the staff   | 
| jimmy|    cook the meal  |
```

```
<apex:page  showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardController="lead"  recordSetVar="leadVar" standardStylesheets="false" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false">


    <table>
                   <apex:repeat value="{!leadVar}" var="ledVar">
                   <apex:repeat value="{!ledVar.AttachedContentNotes}" var="noteVar">
      
                   <tr>
                       <td style="border: 2px  "><apex:outputText value="{!noteVar.Title }"/></td> 
                       <td style="border: 2px  "><apex:outputText value="{!noteVar.Title }"/></td>
                   </tr>
                  </apex:repeat>
      </apex:repeat>
    </table>
```

when I preview its show nothing (empty vf page ).its work  for an account to  contact (when standard object  `account` ) but not working with  lead to notes

Comment: Deleting and reposting questions that are not received well (instead of editing them to improve them) may in the long run result in the system declining further posts from you. Please make sure to read through [ask] and [help/on-topic] to ensure the best reception for your posts.

Comment: [`AttachedContentNotes`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_attachedcontentnote.htm) includes all `ContentNote` records. If you are in Classic, you may be using `Note` instead of `ContentNote`. You'll need to ensure you understand the Note schema and which one you are using.

Comment: i tried with ``Note ``  but it give me the error ``  Invalid field Note for SObject Lead ``

Comment: @DavidReed when I review the question it's fine when I post the question the format is not okay.

Comment: @fawadkhan if you're getting the error `Invalid field Note for SObject Lead`, have you verified you're using the right api name to get the child notes?

Comment: @NickCook How to verify? there is no field  ``Note `` in Lead

Comment: @fawadkhan That's the point. The error you got said there is no field called Note. I'm assuming you want the relationship field, which is probably Notes

Comment: so I need to create a relationship with Notes ( lookup )?